# Odoo SAAS: Add field from associated model into a tree view of another model

Tags: odoo, saas, odoo-9

I have 2 fields in res.partner that I would like to display in a tree view for account.invoice based on the partner_id field. I'm wondering how I can do that (reference another model and field) through the tree view web interface, due to the SaaS version not allowing programmatic access.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create related field in you account.invoice model to the fields of  res.partner

```
x_invoice_preference=fields.Selection(related="partner_id.x_invoice_preference")
```

it's a good practice to name the related field the same name in the other model

Little exemple :

```
class class1(models.Model):
   _name = 'table1'
   name = fields.Char()

class class2(models.Model):
  _name = 'table2'
  table1_id = fields.Many2one('table1','table 1');
  #this how you create a related field in order to 
  #show it in the form or the tree when you select the value of the many2one field it
  # will have the same value of the vield name of the tabl1 
  name = fields.Char(related="table1_id.name",readonly=True)
#field_name                  m2onField.field_name
```

Comment: tell me if you didn't understan my answer

Comment: Hey Charif, thanks for the reply. The field is 'x_invoice_preference' of type 'selection' in model 'res.partner'. I created the x_invoice_preference field of type selection in account.invoice, and under related field (under the advanced properties tab) I put the following:  x_invoice_preference = fields.SameType(related="partner_id.x_invoice_preference"). When saveing the model, I receive this : Unknown field name 'x_invoice_preference = fields' in related field 'x_invoice_preference = fields.SameType(related="partner_id.x_invoice_preference")'
None ... what am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: if the field is a Selection than you need to do this   x_invoice_preference=fields.Selection(related="partner_id.x_invoice_preference")

Comment: with my new edit answer you should understand the related field and how the works

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I am using the SaaS version which doesn't allow me to modify the model programmatically, but through the web interface. I went into the account.invoice model and added a new field. I named it the same as the res.partner field and went into "Advanced Properties" tab and added "partner_id.x_invoice_preference" to the "Related Field" value. That automatically forced the field type to "selection" and I just entered the same "Selection Options" as the res.partner field. Then I just added the field "x_invoice_preferences" to the tree view and there was my data.. Thanks again!

Comment: I wrote up a small post that explains how to do it in Odoo 9 SaaS, as I thought that might be a bit more helpful as well. http://haplesstechnoweenie.com/post/148001332770/cross-model-data-referencing-in-odoo-saas-views  Thanks again @charif !

Comment: i'm very happy for you nice don you did a lot of work thank you